# How do can I load model and change materials before showing it in the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to be able to show a model in the forge viewer but before the model shows I need to change the materials from its defaults. Currently I register the Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT and when I receive the event I hide the model, change the materials and then show the model. This works except that the default model displays in the viewer for a second or two before I can hide it. How can I prevent that from happening?

After initializing the viewer here is code that loads the document. If I try and hide the model as indicated in the commented code below the viewer returns this error. I have to wait for the geometry loaded event before I can hide it.

wgs.js?v=v3.3:17876 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGeometryList' of undefined
    at RenderScene.getGeometryList (wgs.js?v=v3.3:17876)
    at Viewer3DImpl.onLoadComplete (viewer3D.js?v=v3.3:32002)

Here is the code I'm, running:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
  documentId, (doc) => { 
    var geometryItems = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), { 'type': 'geometry' }, true);
    if (geometryItems.length > 0) {

      viewer.load(doc.getViewablePath(geometryItems[0]), null, (model) => {
        // Document loaded

        // Can't hide model here, viewer returns an error because geometry
        // is not loaded
        //viewer.hideModel(model.id);
        resolve(model.id);
      }); // show 1st view on this document...
    }
  },
  function (errorMsg) { // onErrorCallback
    console.log('Load Document returned error message: ' + errorMsg);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply show a pre-canned jpg image preview in place of the forge canvas.

ie. 
 1. Hide the forge canvas with style 'display:none'
 2. Show your preview-jpg in place of the forge canvas
 3. wait for TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT event, like this...

https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-pdf-report/blob/6babb6d7332b6cdb983f57e7d140ff59a5136705/docs/index.html#L44

4. Hide the forge canvas with style 'display:block'
5. Hide your preview-jpg.

Comment: Thanks, If I hide the canvas I get this error: Rendering to a canvas that was resized to zero. If you see this message you may be accidentally leaking a viewer instance. ErrorCode:14.

Comment: ah ok.  Just put a z-index:2 on the preview-jpg, so that it sits over the top of the canvas.  then hide the preview-jpg once the TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT has completed.  (ie. and don't hide the forge canvas)