# When to load custom Panorama extension

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am trying to follow [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/iphone-panorama-forge-viewer) to customize the viewer to look around a model by tilting. When I load this extension from onModelLoadSuccess, it works for some models but crashes the viewer on larger models. If I load it from an event later in the load process, such as GEOMETRY_LOADED, the model partially loads but some objects don't get rendered. Which event is the right one to load this extension from? And is there a way to make it behave on larger models, >50MB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem...I had to up the memory limit on the viewer. I guess the constant screen refresh eats memory.

```
  var config3d = {
                        memory: {
                            limit:  1000 // in MB
                        }
                    };

                    var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
                    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv, config3d);
```

Does the OTG format work for models coming from BIM 360 Docs?

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting on the TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT event, like this...

https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-pdf-report/blob/6babb6d7332b6cdb983f57e7d140ff59a5136705/docs/index.html#L44

taken from: [How do can I load model and change materials before showing it in the Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558587/how-do-can-i-load-model-and-change-materials-before-showing-it-in-the-forge-view/51574897#51574897)

to load larger models... you may want to consider the upcoming OTG format (which you can try through BIM360 design collaboration)

Comment: Just brainstorming here, but is it possible to modify the extension so that it ignores slight device movements/shakes? I believe some of the rendering problems could be helped by it not having to re-render on every slight movement. Maybe some kind of tolerance on the orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

yes - there's two improvements here...

1. (easy) add a low-pass filter to take out human 'shakes' and low-quality MEMs sensor shakes ( see what I did for http://pano.autodesk.com )
2. (hard) use the Forge Viewer, as a pano renderer.

For 2., take a screenshot of the ForgeViewer to a half-cube-map (use the screenshot API 10 times... 2x [front, left, right, top, bottom]. Then stitch them into the inside of a cube.  Now you've got a pano, locked to the camera position.  When the user teleports to a new position, or the person turns past 180' from front
   view, regenerate the cubemap/pano.  This technique is great for large scenes with lots of mesh-popping, and you're phone slow... and you've run out of options. ;-)