# Forge Viewer Optimization

Tags: autodesk-forge

When using Forge Viewer with large model and browser loads svf model, over 840 MB is transferred. On mobile devices page loading failed. Is there a possibility to load model partly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only) to load a model partially - in a nutshell you'd need to pass the nodes' IDs (dbids) in when loading the model like below:

```
const options = { ids:[1,2,3 ...] }
viewer.start/loadModel/loadDocumentNode(document,geometry,options)
```

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. Exactly what I need. But does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753717/12360593) solution to set memory limit help to load large models?

Comment: Another question that has been arisen with using method of loading model with fixed number of ids. When ids are passed in options the property of the element changed to inappropriate. For instance, [wall](https://yadi.sk/i/4oQ74sq6MsQAMw) could become a [foundation slab](https://yadi.sk/i/3IFpTgNKgvL4ZQ) and so on.

Comment: That could perhaps help but you'd only have so much memory available on mobile for each tab ... mobile browsers tend to enforce smaller limits. Did you pass in the correct dbids? If so can you send the offending model file (upload to an online drive of choice and drop the link) to forge.help@autodesk.com along with the problematic ids so we can look into it...

Comment: I sent email with detailed description. Actually this behavior is going on different models. And sure I use correct dbids, which I get from Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT