# optimization of Autodesk forge viewer and role wise visualization of model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

This time i have two questions.

**1. In development phase I was working with some free Revit files which is less than 200mb, and they were taken more than 20 Sec for loading. How to optimize this process so can viewer can work smoothly with  large files (like 2-5GB).**

My second question is like a movie story

**2. Let's consider there is one hotel model with some vaults, so I wanted to hide this vault area (which includes AC ducts, electrical wiring and some other utilities) from everyone excluding some team.
How can I archive this type of functionality inside forge viewer?**

Answer (score 2):

You can load only selected elements with this [approch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262885/12360593). It can be two-barrel shot: for model loading optimization and hiding some elements on the current view.

Comment: Thanks Andrei I tried this approach , but unable to hide whole rooms. And it doesn't make any major impact on loading.

Comment: What impact do you expect to achieve? 1. Open Google Dev Tools in Chrome. 2. Open network tab. 3. Load model full model with all ids. Check the amount of transferred information. 4. Load model with smaller number of ids. Check the amount of transferred information. 5. Compare the values. Less data => faster loading speed.

Comment: but in my case i want to show everything excepts some hidden room. what should i show to the users while viewer load.suggest me what you think right now i am working on one hotel model.

Comment: You may try to use this [solution](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces) to generate rooms in svf models. By I have not try this approach yet. And I don't know the best way to tie ids of elements to that generated rooms. I suppouse you will need a parameter in the element to identify to which room this element belongs.